# Is there a difference between imports in/outside of methods?

Tags: python

Is there any difference between those two imports? Apart from the scope of the import.

**Either the inner or outer import**
of course the inner import would be *useless* if the outer already exists

```
import os

class foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        import os
        path = os.path.join('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're executed at different times. The one inside the function will be executed only when the method is executed, and it will be executed every time the method is called. This is not usually a problem (normally, the module is loaded only once and you just get another reference to the same object), but some may find it philosophiocally objectionable and it *could* have different behavior if other code does stupid things with `sys.modules` or import hooks.

The exception is `from ... import *` anywhere except at module level: It's heavily discouraged and even illegal in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well `id` wise the object are the same, meaning they both are referring to the same module object.

There doesn't seem to be a point in importing it within the method. Since `os` is already within the `global` scope of the module, therefore whether you import `os` or not inside `bar` it wouldn't make a difference. Yes, if you do and `bar` is function that is called many time then `import os` will have a slight hit on the performance.